# What's the word similar to jittery in spelling or pronunciation, but means some privately-run transportation by small vehicles?

Tags: word-request, american-english

What's the word similar to jittery in spelling or pronunciation, but means some privately-run transportation by small vehicles?
For example, there are such transportation services going to New York City from towns nearby.

Comment: Are you thinking of livery cabs? Mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxis_of_New_York_City

Comment: not really. I can't open Wikipedia till someone teachs me to climb over GFW

Answer (score 20):

It's "jitney".

In the early 20th century, jitney was US slang for a 'nickel' (an American 5 cent coin) and came to be used for a mode of public transportation, often using small vehicles, that only cost that sum.

Now the word has a variety of specific use that varies from city to city.  In some places it means an unlicensed and illegal taxi.  In others (eg Atlantic city) it means a legal mini-bus service.

The word is unknown outside of American (and Canadian) English

Comment: [What to do when someone answers your question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

[jeepney](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/jeepney#google_vignette) is possible.

> NOUN
> (in the Philippines) a jeep that has been customized and converted into a taxi

In *jeepney transportation*,  it is an attributive noun modifying transportation.

Edit

I add **jitney**, which the OP correctly suggested, and Michael correctly explained.

Etymonline has an entry for **jitney** (n.) "bus which carries passengers for a fare," 1915, short for jitney bus (1906) ...

**Jeepney** came later.

Comment: Thanks! It's jitney

Comment: Thanks to you too; I've now learned this different spelling I was earlier unaware of:).

Comment: @tim  Please don't answer in comments.  Please use "Post an answer" to write an answer to the question.  (even if it is your own question, self answers are encouraged)

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore - 'jitney' came first.  In the early 20th century, jitney was US slang for a 'nickel' (an American 5 cent coin) and came to be used for a mode of public transportation, often using small vehicles, that only cost that sum. In the mid-20th century, the word 'jitney' was combined with 'jeep' to create 'jeepney', meaning "a Philippine jitney bus converted from a jeep." The Willys Jeep was a World War 2 US military vehicle, sold in large numbers post-war.